# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' React

Tags: reactjs, json, syntax-error

It's been days I've been trying to run react without a CDN, first I've got the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module", that I solved by using .mjs instead of .js.

But now, I'm this new error that I'm unable to solve.

Here is my JS code :

```
import { React } from 'react';
React = require('react');
import { ReactDOM } from 'react-dom';
ReactDOM = require('react-dom');


function Page () {
    return (
     <div>
     <h1>Test</h1>
     </div>  
    )
}


ReactDOM.render( <Page />,document.getElementById("root"))
```

My HTLM code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="index.mjs"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The console error :

```
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
file:///c:/Users/Tristan/OneDrive/Bureau/REACT/InstallTest/index.mjs:9
     <div>
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at ESMLoader.moduleStrategy (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:117:18)
    at ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:337:14)
    at async link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:70:21)
```

I don't know if those infos are enough to find a solution.

Comment: Are you building your react app and hosting the contents of the build output directory?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing, and for hosting content, I'm actually not sure. This is my first React app, but I assume using Vite everything is set up automatically right ?

Comment: Very confused as to what you are doing and what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to host your application (as in build the project and upload to some hosting service) or are you trying to run it locally? If locally, are you trying to run distribution code or the development code? Perhaps update the question with your run/host steps

Comment: You're right, I think I spotted the problem. I'm running it locally and I saw the following message on my terminal : "npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead."

Comment: I´ve soldved the hosting problem but remains the syntax one.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a build tool such as [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) or Create-React-App? It will handle all of this for you, and provide you with a boilerplate template. Configuring all of this stuff manually is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here my Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "vite-project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.0",
    "vite": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```